# How to add two numbers in One Text Box in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

[image]JavaScript Code Is:

```
function add(){
  var addThs = document.getElementById('demo').value;
}
```

Html Code Is:

```
<input type="text" id="demo">
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add two numbers in one text box"?

Comment: Question can be interpreted several different ways. It's not up to us to guess . See [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()` to take the array of operands and `reduce()` to get the sum .

**Please note:** the solution below will also work for multiple `+` like (`5+7+9+6`):

```js
function add(){
  var el = document.getElementById('demo');
  var val = el.value.split('+');
  el.value = val.reduce((a,c)=> a + Number(c), 0);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="demo">
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

Comment: hmmm `++1+++1++`

Comment: Using `Number` on `a` is not necessary since you've set the starting value to `0`.

Comment: @Olian04, that is not the case in the question. If you really need that the solution is `el.value.split('+').filter(i=>i)`.......thanks.

Comment: I did, replacing `Number(a)` with `a` works fine. *Can you check*?

Comment: @Ivan, I thought you were talking about replacing both `Number()`........

Answer (score -1):

First, split your string by the `+` sign:

```
document.getElementById('demo').value.split('+');
```

Will return an array of two elements (given that the input is correct).

I am using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign the first to `a` and the second to `b`:

```
var input = document.getElementById('demo').value;
var [a,b] = input.split('+');
```

You have then assign your variable to the `textContent` property of an element.

Don't forget to convert those strings to actual integers to make the operation work.

---

Here is the full code:

```js
function add() {
  var input = document.getElementById('demo').value;
  var [a,b] = input.split('+');
  document.getElementById('show').textContent = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="demo">
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>

<div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: How does this *"add two numbers"*?